# Hide Android soft keyboard on enter in Jelly Bean / KitKat

Tags: android, keyboard, android-softkeyboard

I want the keyboard to hide on `Enter` for a certain `EditText`. 
I've implemented this:

```
myEditText.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onEditorAction(TextView textView, int i, KeyEvent keyEvent) {
        if ((keyEvent!= null) && (keyEvent.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)) {
            InputMethodManager in = (InputMethodManager)getActivity().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            in.hideSoftInputFromWindow(editTextAnswer.getApplicationWindowToken(), InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

This works for a number of keyboards, but not the AOSP one (tested with both Jelly Bean and KitKat devices). I've tried adding

```
android:imeOptions="actionGo"
```

to the `EditText` and checking the action ID, but that didn't work either. I added logging code within `onEditorAction(...)` and nothing gets logged when I hit the `Enter` key on the AOSP keyboard. Is there some way I can achieve the behaviour I'm looking for?

Answer (score 2):

Try setting an **OnKeyListener**:

```
myEditText.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onKey(View arg0, int arg1, KeyEvent arg2) {
        switch (arg1) {
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER:
            InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(myEditText.getWindowToken(), 0);
            return true;
        default:
            break;
        }
        return false;
    }

});
```

and try changing your **OnEditorActionListener** to the following:

```
myEditText.setOnEditorActionListener(new OnEditorActionListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onEditorAction(TextView arg0, int actionId,
                    KeyEvent arg2) {
                // hide the keyboard and search the web when the enter key
                // button is pressed
                if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_GO
                        || actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE
                        || actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_NEXT
                        || actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEND
                        || actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEARCH
                        || (arg2.getAction() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)) {
                    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(myEditText.getWindowToken(), 0);

                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
   });
```

Depending on the EditText, different enter keys are shown, sometimes it's says done, sometimes enter, sometimes go. You need to use all the flags for the possible states of the enter button, in order to get it. The KEYCODE_ENTER isn't usually passed to the EditorActionListener, although I include it for physical keyboards, but you **can** catch KEYCODE_ENTER with the OnKeyListener.

Comment: I added an **onKeyListener** and have edited my **onEditorActionListener** as per your suggestions, but the results don't change. Again, I added logging code and nothing gets logged when I use the AOSP keyboard.

Comment: Wow, that is very odd. I was going to suggest that you use the imeOption "actionGo" but I see that you are already using that. I would suggest changing around your layout. It could be that there is some odd piece of the layout causing this issue. Also, if you have an OnTouchListener set for the EditText, it **could** potentially mess with the above listeners. If you have set one, make sure you return false from it.

Comment: I don't have any OnTouchListeners set. Interestingly, a quick search says that imeOption "actionGo" will only work if I also add singleLine=true, which is not what I want.

Comment: Have you tried switching to a different imeOption like "actionDone" to see if that worked?

Comment: Yes, I've tried that as well. Again, it only worked with android:singleLine="true".